# What does "チョーイミシンッ" mean?

Tags: translation, katakana

In the sentence:

> "重大{じゅうだい}な事実{じじつ}っすか！なんかチョーイミシンッ！"

I can't seem to find the meaning for the second part "チョーイミシンッ".

Answer (score 3):

It's 超 ("super") + 意味深 ("profound") in kanji.